# Can the moment coefficient at the quarter chord point be negative?

Tags: aerodynamics

After a calculation I obtained a value of -0.318 and I am just checking to see if this is reasonable.
An explanation for the consequences of having a negative value here would also be appreciated if possible.

Comment: Why don't you show your math and explain more clearly what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: I tried to give a somewhat general answer below .. I guess for clarification, some more details would be helpful .. how did you define your coordinate system, maybe a sketch?

Answer (score 2):

Positive or negative here depends on the coordinate system you have used. An airfoil producing positive lift (up) will invoke a positive circulation, and that will require a counter-acting torque, which is then negative (pitch-down).

Some more detailed explanation can be found on wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitching_moment

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerodynamic_center

(I haven't checked either for correctness).

Furthermore, the CM (torque coefficient) is usually a function of the angle of attack - so - provide a simple example - on a symmetrical profile, running negative angles of attack, there will be a positive CM. (Aerobatic planes eg use that sometimes)